# Baryons with $J^P=\frac{3}{2}^+$

Tags: particle-physics

For Baryons with $J^P=\frac{3}{2}^+$ we have $\Delta^{++}$, $\Delta^{+}$, $\Delta^{0}$ and $\Delta^{-}$. But why isn't there a $\Delta^{--}=|\bar u\bar u\bar u\rangle $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [baryons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon) are (conventionally) made of three quarks, not three antiquarks. The state $|\bar u\bar u\bar u\rangle$ does exist, but it is just the antiparticle of $\Delta^{++} =|u u u\rangle$ and would be written $\bar \Delta^{++}$ (note the bar on top).

Comment: Ah, I see. So what are particles with 3 components called where antiquarks are allowed?

Comment: Particles with three antiquarks would be called antibaryons! And to be clear, there are no particles with three constituents where, say, one is a quark and the other two are antiquarks.

Comment: @VashVI AFAIK they do not exist, there are some hypthesized I suppose , in what are called exotic hadrons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_hadron

Comment: So for example $|dd\bar u\rangle$ does not exist? Wow, I really didn't know that. Are there specific reasons as to why that is?

Comment: @Buh: Right, $|dd\bar u\rangle$ does not exist since it is not "color neutral" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge). Due to color confinement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement) only color neutral combinations of quarks exist as observable particles.